# Can't reset or turn GFCI switch on. What could be wrong?

Tags: electrical, gfci

Needless to say I'm not an electrical expert. I would pay someone but the cheapest someone will charge where I live is 200 just to come out and see it. I feel like it is something easy I could probably do once I turn all the electricity at the house off.

Something tripped this outlet. It is in the bathroom and it is connected to the ceiling light. I can't press the rest or test button. Like I can push them but they don't click like my other GFCI switches do. I turned all the breakers in the box off and back on but still no luck. I reset/tested every GFCI switch in the house.

I don't know what to do or test/check next. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: There is a chance that the GFCI has bit the dust(it is busted), if so a simple replace job should fix it.  Make sure by checking three times that the power is off on that circuit(multimetre,voltage tester).   Other possibly is a big problem on that circuit, maybe mouse/rat chewed the wires.

Comment: Is there anything you’re leaving out about how it came to be connected that way? Things that suddenly changed matter, esp. if they are planned work.

Comment: @crip659 So it is possible they die? I didn't know electrical outlets can die.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica "how it came to be connected that way"? Not sure what you are asking. It was working fine and then it stopped. Someone might have plugged a vac into it but not sure. That is the only thing I can assume anyone would use that outlet for.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan  Most plain outlets/switches are usually good for the life of the house.  Start adding extra stuff into them for GFCs/AFCs circuits, their lifetimes can be much shorter, more stuff to fail.

Comment: These GFCI outlets are controlled by electronics. How often do other electronic devices in your house fail? Yeah, that happens. :( Even regular outlets can fail due to plastic cracking allowing things to loosen.

Comment: "It was working fine and then stopped" <- that's what I needed to know.  (As we can guess, we often get questions where that is untrue, and it elps a great deal to know).

Answer (score 3):

If replacing the device yourself is something you'd consider then you're all set to pull it out of the wall and test it.

With the power off, remove the faceplate and then remove the device itself from the wall. Don't disconnect any wires just yet; only remove the two mounting screws so that you can pull the outlet and its attached wires out of the junction box. It should have one white-insulated wire (or maybe two or more) on one side and one or more black wires on the other side.

If there are two pairs of wires connected to the outlet, turn it one way or another -- bend the wires to one side, for example -- so that you can read the text printed on the back of it. You should be able to find the word LINE associated with one of the black and white wire pairs and the word LOAD associated with the other pair. Carefully disconnect the black and white wire from the LOAD terminals.

Arrange the bare wires and terminals in a safe way and turn on the power. Try to reset the GFCI (be careful not to grip the outlet by its bare terminals!).

If it does reset there's a legitimate problem downstream of the GFCI. We can tackle that as a separate question.

If it does not reset, test whether there's power on the wires coming into the outlet. A volt meter is needed for this task because the volt meter can confirm whether you have 120 volts between the black and the white wires (ie, that the white/neutral wire is connected). A non-contact voltage tester can't do that.

If there is power at the outlet but it won't reset with LOAD disconnected, the outlet is defective.

Comment: I can do that. I didn't realize/think that outlets can go bad. I will try replacing. Thanks!

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan Before you remove _any_ wiring, make sure you take pictures of _BOTH_ sides of the outlet so you know _exactly_ which wire goes where! If you don't believe me, look at the number of questions here about "help! I undid all this wiring and now I can't figure out how to put it back together to make it all work!" You can even use little bits of colored electrical tape to identify each individual wire for your pictures, if you think that will help.